# no media detected on a usb flash drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, fdisk

I have a Kingston DT MicroDuo 3.0 and it was working fine till it didn't mount on Windows, Mac nor Ubuntu

It appears in the disk utility as `/dev/sdd` and in the volumes area it shows `no media detected`

I  tried `sudo fdisk dev/sdd/` but got

```
fdisk: unable to open dev/sdd/: no such file or directory
```

and then I tried `sudo umount dev/sdd/`but got the error:

```
umount:  dev/sdd/: not mounted
```

It doesn't matter if I need to format the drive, but I need it back into a working condition.

Comment: Is that a typo?  It should be `sudo fdisk /dev/sdd` or `sudo umount /dev/sdd`.

Comment: Run "dmesg -T | tail " after you insert the USB disk. Can you see your disk got detected? It will complain if it has some error with the disk. If it detects, you can try " gparted " command to format the disk and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

These are all the symptoms of a broken USB stick.  Please replace it.

To be absolutely sure that it is indeed broken, install the `smartmontools` package:

```
sudo apt-get install smartmontools
```

then run:

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdd
```

and depending on the error message you'll know for sure that it's broken.

*Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news*

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: This works with an USB stick? … Checking

Comment: It used to be the case that very few devices were supported, but I forgot that it's not a *requirement*. Let's see what the OP says...

Comment: the device isn't with me atm, as soon as am able to try, i'll post the answer, sry.

Comment: I would like to confirm that this program and command does in fact verify that a USB Stick is fried. Just tested it on one and sure enough. Unknown bridge.

Comment: @BradynClaycomb: edited.  Worthy of an upvote now?  **:-)**